# How to achieve a better url configuring only web.config

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have an url like

```
catSubcat.aspx?catid=31
```

and it displays cricket page. this catId comes from Database.
I am asked to dislay it like

```
> Cricket
```

this catName = Cricket is present in Database, but it is not present Code-behind(Web forms).
I am asked to do this only in web.config and forbidden to touch aspx and .cs files. How can I do this. Thanks in advance.

**After Edit**
This is my rewrite rule. And I want to get /CRICKET, but find error in rewriting.

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^catSubcat\.aspx$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^catid=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;title=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="catSubcat/{C:1}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^catSubcat/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="catSubcat.aspx?catid={R:1}&amp;title={R:2}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="Outbound" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^(.*/)catSubcat\.aspx\?catid=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;(?:amp;)?title=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}catSubcat/{R:2}/{R:3}/" />
            </rule>
            <preConditions>
                <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                </preCondition>
            </preConditions>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```